# JS UnitTesting a method chain in Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have a ES6 method like so:

```
/**
* Builds a knex object with offset and limit
* @param {Object} pagination
* @param {number} pagination.count - limit query to
* @param {number} pagination.start - start query at
* @returns {QueryBuilder}
*/
buildPagination (pagination) {
    if (_.isEmpty(pagination)) {
        return this;
    }

    let count = pagination.count;
    let start = pagination.start;

    this.knex = this.knex.offset(start);

    if (count !== undefined) {
        this.knex = this.knex.limit(count);
    }

    return this;
}
```

And my test looks like:

```
describe("#buildPagination", () => {
    let knex;
    let b;
    let pagination;

    beforeEach(() => {
        knex = sinon.stub();
        knex.offset = sinon.stub();
        knex.limit = sinon.stub();
        b = new QueryBuilder(knex);
        pagination = {
            start: 3,
            count: 25
        };
    });

    it.only("should attach limit and offset to knex object", () => {
        let res = b.buildPagination(pagination).knex;

        console.log(res);

        assert(res.offset.calledOnce);
        assert(res.offset.calledWith(3));
        assert(res.limit.calledAfter(res.offset))
        // assert(res.knex.limit.calledWith(25));
    });
});
```

The error I am running into is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'limit' of undefined`. The error is happening with this line: `this.knex = this.knex.limit(count);`

Comment: what is the value here? this.knex = this.knex.offset(start). Cannot read the property 'limit' of undefined means this.knex is undefined.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Doesn't make sense why it's not able to find the knex property because if I run this test without checking the limit call, it passes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an standalone demonstration:

```
var knex    = sinon.stub();  
knex.limit  = sinon.stub();
knex.offset = sinon.stub();

knex = knex.offset();
```

At this point, `knex` is `undefined` because your stubs don't actually return anything. When you subsequently call `knex.limit()`, you get a `TypeError`.

If you want to allow chaining, your method stubs need to return the `knex` stub:

```
knex.limit  = sinon.stub().returns(knex);
knex.offset = sinon.stub().returns(knex);
```

Comment: Thanks!! I wound up realizing this shortly after posting my question, but never came back to it. Thanks for answering, though! It'll stand as a point of reference!